# C# List files in directory with wildcard on directory

Tags: c#

I'm trying to list files on the directory using a wildcard in the directory name.

Something like:

```
var fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Users\\*\\Desktop\\statistics.txt");
```

When I'm trying to run this I get an exception about illegal characters.

I don't know what is the username on each PC in my network so it isn't possible to use regex (I think so).

So how can I search for files in a directory using the wildcard on the directory name?

Comment: To use a wildcard in the directory name, you have to enumerate the directories first; then get the files from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending what you want to do with files inside wildcarded path, you can start with:

```cs
var dirs = Directory.GetDirectories("c:\\Users", "Desktop*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach (var d in dirs)
{
    var files = Directory.GetFiles(d, "statistics.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One potential option is an overloaded method of `Directory.GetFiles`, [here is documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-7.0#system-io-directory-getfiles(system-string-system-string-system-io-searchoption)).

Using that method, your solution may looks something like:

```
Directory.GetFiles(
@"C:\Users",
"statistics.txt",
SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Note that `SearchOption.AllDirectories` will search *all* subdirectories of `"C:\Users"` folder. This may have a negative impact on performance, but if you are trying to return all files in a directory and subsequent subdirectories with a certain name, I think it is your best option.

Comment: If you really want just to desplay the files on each users desktop you should then filter all files that include "\\desktop\\" in their .FullPath. So you at least filter out the other / unnecessary directories